# Extract data send from Angularjs in multipart POST to Nodejs and write to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am facing a serious issue while uploading file from web browser using angular js as front end part. When I click send, I route it to Nodejs express server. But I am not able to get my data.

My mission is just to browse and upload form browser and write on the local disk using node js.

I have got lot of links but no help.

Answer (score 1):

Use multer module to upload files..

```
var multer = require('multer');
```

use middleware.

```
app.use(multer({dest: “./uploads/”}));
app.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){ 
if (req.files) { 
    console.log(util.inspect(req.files));
    if (req.files.myFile.size === 0) {
                return next(new Error("Hey, first would you select a file?"));
    }
    fs.exists(req.files.myFile.path, function(exists) { 
        if(exists) { 
            res.json({success: true}); 
        } else { 
            res.jend({success: false); 
        } 
    }); 
} 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I also just came across alternate solution by the time and its woking.
[Alternative solution using 'connect'](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/5327b0f1-2d29-4c9b-b031-04b397107300/Upload%20and%20Download%20File%20in%20Node%20JS#.VbjvNCQ71h4) Thanks again.